# What's the temperature returned by performanceCounter > Thermal Zone Information?

Tags: c#, performancecounter, temperature

What's the temperature returned by performanceCounter > Thermal Zone Information?

I've searched in Google but haven't found anything so far...

[image]

**EDIT**

I don't know how to vote for Dmitry Bychenko comment as answer. But he appears to be right. The value i get matches my CPU temperature in Kelvin. I've confirmed this using Everest to get the CPU temperature in Celsius and making the conversion to Kelvin. My computer CPU is a intel i3.

So this is (apparently) a way get the CPU temperature in Celsius:

Add a performanceCounter, in CategoryName select "Thermal Zone Information", in CounterName "Temperature", and in InstanceName "_TZ.THRM".

Add a timer (i'm using a interval of 1000) and a label (whose text will display the temperature). Add the code:

```
label1.Text = (performanceCounter1.NextValue() - 273.15).ToString() + " °C";
```

Ps: sorry for the poor English

Comment: It should be CPU temperature (Throttle is way to cool down the CPU)

Comment: I've added one timer (1 second refresh) and a label to get the value: `label9.Text = performanceCounterTEMP.NextValue().ToString();` The value returned oscillates between 322 and about 326... Can this be the CPU temp?

Comment: This appears to be indeed the CPU temperature in Kelvin... Doing the conversion, it match the temperature results i get from Everest in Celsius...

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out many years ago, the performance counter reports the temperature in degrees Kelvin.  Some (hopefully relevant) Microsoft documentation can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/thermal-management-in-windows

Comment: The answer is good, but the link should be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/examples--requirements-and-diagnostics